# Software trigger for intermec CN51 barcode scanner running in Android platform

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner, intermec

I just want to know how to trigger the barcode scanner of the intermec cn51 device through software events rather than pressing the blue hardware button for the scanner. The device is running in **Android 4.1.1**

If anyone out there who has tried developing apps on this device, please any response is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are writing a native android app?

Download their SDK: http://www.intermec.com/products/cmptrcn51a/downloads.aspx

It contains some sample android code for integrating with the barcode reader.

You'll need to register (free) to download the SDK.